# vue.js mode for css

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have this BaseComponent used and configures in another component as followed:

```
<BaseTitle
      v-slot="{ highlightClass }"
      :color="mode === 'faq' ? 'dark' : 'secondary'"
      v-bind="__titleProps"
      :text-uppercase="mode === 'incentive'"
      highlight-type="colorize-uppercase-bold"
      :class="{ 'font-weight-normal': mode === 'faq' }"
    >
```

On this element I have a css-hover class

```
    .InfoTile {
      &:hover {
        .answer {
          background-color: $transparent-primary;
          opacity: 1;
        }
    
        .question {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
```

When I use the „incentive" mode I need to use another hover background-color.
Is there a way to use another hover depending on the mode I use?

Comment: You'll have to add a class based on mode just like `font-weight-normal` class and add hover styles for that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, is totally possible.

You just need to create 2 differentes css classes, between normal mode and incentive, that will have 2 differentes hover, etc.

you'll made a conditional term checking if mode === incentive.

But, the first thing you need to do is to set more than one classes in your component, you're using one already.

so, just do something like this.

```
:class="[{ 'font-weight-normal': mode === 'faq' }, mode === incentive ? 'cssClass1': 'cssClass2']"
```